# Thin space in bibliography not working with amsmath loaded (biblatex + IEEE style)

Tags: biblatex, spacing, bibliographies, amsmath, ieee-style

Related to [GitHub plk / biblatex issue #910](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/910#issue-480449391).

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[style=ieee]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @Article{A,
        title = {A\,b c},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
    Text~\cite{A}.
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Apart from the incorrect output, compilation with MiKTeX ends with errors: `Missing number, treated as zero. \end`, `Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \end`.

Can someone provide an idea what to do to allow the usage of thin spaces (`\,`) in bibliographic titles in documents like the example above?

Comment: This must surely be a bug in biblatex/biber. Have you reported it at [this site](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues)?

Comment: In the meantime, prefixing `\,` with `\protect`, and thus writing the field as `title = {A\protect\,b c},`, should keep you in business.

Comment: Using `\addnbthinspace` also works. I agree that `biblatex-ieee` shouldn't do this though. Interesting, the standard `biblatex` numeric style works with `\,`, so it must be something to do with `biblatex-ieee`.

Comment: Bug reported as [Issue #910](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/910#issue-480449391).

Comment: Just to notice, some other entry types, for example, `@Book`, seem to be unaffected by this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`biblate-ieee` applies `\MakeSentenceCase*` to titles of some (but not all) entry types. `@article`s get their title sentence-cased, but `@book`s don't, that explains the observation in the comments.

`\MakeSentenceCase` is a very complex and fragile macro since string manipulation is somewhat tricky in LaTeX. In particular `\MakeSentenceCase` performs quite a lot of expansions and tries to iterate through the string one character at a time.

Standard LaTeX defines `\,` as a robust macro, but `amsmath` defines

```
\renewcommand{\,}{\tmspace+\thinmuskip{.1667em}}
```

which means that `\,` can be expanded (once) and is not robust (its expansion is robust). This expansion causes some issues in the machinery of `\MakeSentenceCase` and produces the error you see.

There are several ways to work around this issue.

1. Make `\,` robust again. Issue

   ```
   \renewrobustcmd{\,}{\tmspace+\thinmuskip{.1667em}}
   ```

   after you've loaded `amsmath`. (Note that `\renewrobustcmd` needs `etoolbox`, which in the MWE is loaded by `biblatex`, so this line should come after loading both `amsmath` and `biblatex`.)
2. `\protect` this `\,` in the `.bib` file (as suggested by [Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5001/mico) [in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/504138/thin-space-in-bibliography-not-working-with-amsmath-loaded-biblatex-ieee-styl#comment1273427_504138))

   ```
   @article{A,
     title = {A\protect\,b c},
   }
   ```
3. Use a different command that is still protected (as suggested by [David Purton](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/87678/david-purton) [in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/504138/thin-space-in-bibliography-not-working-with-amsmath-loaded-biblatex-ieee-styl#comment1273428_504138)), for example `biblatex`'s `\,` equivalent `\addnbthinspace`.

   ```
   @article{A,
     title = {A\addnbthinspace b c},
   }
   ```
4. You can always 'hide' parts of the string from `\MakeSentenceCase` with curly braces.

   ```
   @article{A,
     title = {A{\,}b c},
   }
   ```

   works, but I'm not sure if I would recommend it.

---

Here is an MWE to test the solutions without `biblatex-ieee`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase}{\MakeSentenceCase*{#1}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{A,
  title = {A\,b c},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  Text~\cite{A}.
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```